# MS Access 2007 Insert Query fails to execute

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a simple query to insert a record into a table (P_Case table). I get the values from textboxes in a form (Case_Form). I execute the query when clicking on a command button in the Case_Form. However, the execution fails and I get the error "Query input must contain at least on table or query"!!!

```
INSERT INTO P_Case (Case_Date, Case_Desc, Aff_Person) 
VALUES (Forms!Case_Form![Case Date], Forms!Case_Form![Case Desc], (SELECT Person.ID FROM Person WHERE Person.National_ID=Forms!Case_Form![National ID]));
```

I appreciate your help..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is been a while why I used Access but I doubt you can use subqueries in the `VALUES` statement.

So try something like:

```
INSERT INTO P_Case (Case_Date, Case_Desc, Aff_Person)
SELECT Forms!Case_Form![Case Date]
     , Forms!Case_Form![Case Desc]
     , Person.ID 
FROM Person 
WHERE Person.National_ID=Forms!Case_Form![National ID]
);
```

If that not works you need to get the value from the subquery first and store it into a form variable.